# Implementing PyQGIS code to action when pressing button in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, actions, button

I am interested in the creation of actions in QGIS 3.22. I have a Python script that multiplies the numbers from the fields `"wert1"` and `"wert2"` and writes them to the field `"ergebnis"`.

Here is the corresponding Python script:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

indexErgebnis = layer.fields().indexFromName("ergebnis")
indexFID = layer.fields().indexFromName("id")
print(indexErgebnis)
print(indexFID)
editieren = {}

for x in layer.getFeatures():
  
    fid = x.id()
    print(fid)
    # neuer Wert:
    wert1 = x.attribute("wert1")
    print(wert1)
    wert2 = x.attribute("wert2")
    ergebnis = wert1*wert2
    print(ergebnis)
    editieren[fid] = {indexErgebnis: ergebnis, indexFID: fid}
    
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(editieren)
```

So far so good. Now I now want to embed the script into an action, so that the user only has to click the button of the action in the attribute table to have the calculation performed and inserted into the field `"ergebnis"`.

What syntax changes do I need to consider for actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, open the [Properties Dialog](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-vector-properties-dialog) for your layer and click the [Actions](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#actions-menu) tab. Click the green plus sign to add a new action.

[image]

Set up your Action as seen in the dialog below. Select Python type and check Layer scope. Write whatever you want for the Description and Short Name.

[image]

Paste the following script into the editor, then click OK to exit all dialogs.

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QAction

layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'

layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
indexErgebnis = layer.fields().indexFromName("ergebnis")
indexFID = layer.fields().indexFromName("id")
editieren = {}

for x in layer.getFeatures():
    fid = x.id()
    wert1 = x.attribute("wert1")
    wert2 = x.attribute("wert2")
    ergebnis = wert1*wert2
    editieren[fid] = {indexErgebnis: ergebnis, indexFID: fid}

layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(editieren)

# Refresh the attribute table view
tbl_dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, f'QgsAttributeTableDialog/{layer_id}')
if tbl_dlg:
    action_reload = tbl_dlg.findChild(QAction, 'mActionReload')
    if action_reload:
        action_reload.trigger()
```

Now, open the layer's attribute table to run the action.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a tip with `tbl_dlg = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDialog, f'QgsAttributeTableDialog/{layer_id}')`. BTW how did you learn PyQt ?